# SOAP::Lite always faults in debug mode

Tags: perl, soap

I've had this issue for a while now. Every time I use `SOAP::Lite` in debug mode (whether normal debugging or with something like `NYTProf`) it ends up calling the `on_fault` handler.

I've stepped through and it is due to this error:

```
Attempt to reload SOAP/Lite/Deserializer/XMLSchema2001.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1343)[C:\\Perl\\site\\lib/SOAP/Lite.pm:2328] line 3.
...propagated at C:\\Perl\\site\\lib/SOAP/Lite.pm line 2328.
```

I'm wondering if this is normal and what the best workaround is? Thanks.

Edit: Forgot to mention this is Activestate Perl 5.10.1 on Windows and upgrading is not an option at this time.

Comment: More data to reproduce your problem would be helpful. If you download SOAP::Lite from CPAN and run the unit tests through the debugger, do they exhibit the same problem?  They seem to run fine for me...

Comment: From [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) __Attempt to reload %s aborted.__ `You tried to load a file with use or require that failed to compile once already.`.

Comment: Does this produce an error? `perl -MSOAP::Lite::Deserializer::XMLSchema2001 -e 0`

Comment: That line works, debug or not. It will be hard to break it up as it's embedded in one of our modules but I'll work on isolating it today if I get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Running perl with both -d and -w flags seems to cause an issue in the debugger with the scope of warnings. It complains about redefined subs in this mode, but ignores them if we supply just one or neither of the -d/-w flags.

The issue is in `SOAP::Lite::Deserializer::XMLSchema2001`, the `BEGIN` block maps the `as_*` methods. `dateTime` is in the list twice so we get an error about `as_dateTime` being redefined.

This breaks the initial module compilation, and upon our 2nd attempt produces the error above.